# C# How does ThreadPriority.BelowNormal affect performance?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a web crawler I'm writing. It's currently crawling 30 websites at a time (each one thread) with 2 threads for each website. So 60 in created threads in total. I had some issues where the GUI was locking up. So I added

`System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority = Render` to my GUI thread but that seems to make the GUI thread use 50% of the CPU when I ran the profiling. So I've removed that and now changed the priority of crawling threads to

```
Thread.CurrentThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.BelowNormal;
```

Which seems to of worked well.

I'm trying to figure out the fastest way run to run these threads without the GUI locking up so my question is this.

If there is no GUI processing to be done will these threads run at the same speed as if they didn't have `ThreadPriority.BelowNormal` set? I'm assuming `ThreadPriority.BelowNormal` doesn't constantly make the thread run slowly, it just gives the GUI thread (any other others with a normal priority) priority over it?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpriority(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just means other threads have priority.  As long as the UI isn't doing anything major, the background threads will run efficiently.  (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpriority(v=vs.110).aspx)